# Receiving "Missing credentials in config" when using AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to integrate a lex bot in my web app, this is the code I have written. I have used an identity pool for unauthenticated user. Here is my code

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>Amazon Lex for JavaScript - Sample Application (BookTrip)</title>
 <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.41.0.min.js"></script>
 
  // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
  AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'; // Region
  AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  // Provide your Pool Id here
   IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
   RoleArn: 'arn:aws:cognito-identity:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx',
   

  });
```

But everytime I am receiving the "Missing credentials in config" error. I have also tried using AWSCognito.config.credentials for this but still it is giving the same error. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you making the following call to get the credentials?

```
// Make the call to obtain credentials
AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){

    // Credentials will be available when this function is called.
    var accessKeyId = AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
    var secretAccessKey = AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
    var sessionToken = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;

    // Add your code here that uses the credentials

});

// Do NOT assume that the credentials are valid here
```

Note: The credentials are not available until the callback function is called. A common mistake is writing code outside of the callback assuming that the credentials exist immediately after calling AWS.config.credentials.get().